# Combine 2 custom post types in a single foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

I'm trying to combine 2 custom post types: 1) CPT = event 2) CPT = location, in the same foreach loop.

e.g.

```
<?php
  $events = get_posts( array( post_type => event));
  $locations = get_posts( array( post_type => location));
  foreach($events as $event ) {
    foreach($locations as $location ) {
      echo $event->post_title;
      echo $location->post_title;
    }
  }
?>
```

This however will only duplicate each post title. I also tried the following but it didn't work.

```
<?php
  foreach($events as $index => $event ) {
    $event->post_title;
    $event->post_title[$index];
  }
```

Comment: Define 'combine'. You want all of the posts of type 'event' or 'location' (i.e. in set terms, the *union* of those posts)? Or you need to *join* (or subquery) the events and locations (on some yet-unspecified field) so that you get eventA-locationA, eventB-locationB, ... pairs back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found what you need:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'event'
);

/* Get events */
$events = get_posts( $args );

foreach($events as $event ) {
  echo '<article><h2>';
  $event->post_title;
  echo '<span>';

  /*get location of event*/
  $args2 = array(
    'post_type' => 'location',
    'meta_key' => '_location_ID', 
    'meta_value' => get_post_meta($event->ID,'_location_ID')
  );
  $locations = get_posts( $args2 );
  foreach($locations as $location ) {
    echo $location->post_title;
  }
  echo '</span></h2></article>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want as an output. This should give you a list of all titles:

```
foreach($events as $event ) {
  $titles[]=$event->post_title;
}
foreach($locations as $location ) {
  $titles[]=$location->post_title;
}
echo '<ul>';
foreach($titles as $title ) {
  echo '<li>'.$title.'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: this is on the right track, but I basically need to output something like this: Start Loop `<article><h2>Event Title <span>Location Title</span></h2><article>`//END Loop  They need to have a unique variable to be called in different places inside the loop

Comment: Ok. But how are they related to each other? How do I know which location belongs to which event?

Comment: what if they shared the same _location_ID custom meta field?  So  _location_ID = "same value"

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should do is switch to using WP_Query instead of get_posts and you can do the following quick dirty example:

```
// The Query args
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'event', 'location' )
);

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';

   while( $the_query->have_posts() ){
       $post = $the_query->the_post();
       echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '<li>';
   }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: So I need to output the two different titles from each CPT in the same loop e.g. `<article><h2>Event Title <span>Location Title</span></h2><article>`